# JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: . Row size is larger than: 2097152

Tags: google-bigquery

We tried to upload a file from GoogleCloudStorage but got errors like

> JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: . Row size is larger than: 2097152. (error code: invalid)`.
>   Ten thousand of customers data are stored in oneline.

```
[{"user_id":1,"address": "london", "birthday":xxxx},{"user_id":2,"address": "london", "birthday":xxxx},{"user_id":3,"address": "NY", "birthday":xxxx},....{"user_id":10000,"address": "NY", "birthday":xxxx}]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to load JSON from GCS to GBQ you should transform your data to look like below, with each user info in separate line - this will address row size limit and will comply with `newline delimited JSON` requirement - See more about supported [JSON format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-formats#json_format)

```
{"user_id":1,"address": "london", "birthday":xxxx}
{"user_id":2,"address": "london", "birthday":xxxx}
{"user_id":3,"address": "NY", "birthday":xxxx}
....
{"user_id":10000,"address": "NY", "birthday":xxxx}
```

Comment: Could you please let me know how can we transform into this BQ desired format? I am facing the similar issue.

Comment: @Pasha You need to play logic to get string like above mentioned format json with newline character separated.