# JSON parsing error in table copy from BigQuery to BigQuery table using Java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I'm getting the below error, while I try to simply copy data from one table to another. The temporary files have properly converted the table row into JSON format; however, this error appears:

> JSON temp file : Row 1 -> {"field_0":"mango"}
>
> "Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row
>   starting at position 0: No such field: field_0"

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I can not comment because of my low reputation, but I think that question could be directly related to [JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: . Row size is larger than: 2097152](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651143/json-parsing-error-in-row-starting-at-position-0-row-size-is-larger-than-209)

Your JSON data should look like:

```
{"user_id":1,"address": "london", "birthday":xxxx}
{"user_id":2,"address": "london", "birthday":xxxx}
{"user_id":3,"address": "NY", "birthday":xxxx}
```

And not

```
[{"user_id":1,"address": "london", "birthday":xxxx},
{"user_id":2,"address": "london", "birthday":xxxx},
{"user_id":3,"address": "NY", "birthday":xxxx}]
```

Supported [JSON format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#json_format). I think your tables could be properly converted to JSON format but not the exactly format that BigQuery expects.